# Javascript palindrome check word to see if it's a palindrome

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to determine if a word is a palindrome. A palindrome is a word that is spelled the same way forwards and backwards. I want my code to console.log what I've written but I'm getting an error: unreachable code after return statement.

The line where error starts is: `isWordAPalindrome('word');`?

```js
isWordAPalindrome('word');

function isWordAPalindrome(word) {
  var word = "sherpa,stewie,anna,lil squiggle, racecar, tacocat"
  str[0];
  str.length
  console.log(); {
    if (str.length = 0) {
      return true;
    }
    if (str[0] != str[str.length - 1]) {
      return false;
    }
    return isWordAPalindrome(str.slice(1, str.length - 1));
    isWordAPalindrome('word');
    console.log('sherpa');
    console.log('stewie');
    console.log('anna');
    console.log('lil squiggle');
    console.log('racecar');
    console.log('tacocat');
  }
  console.log(''); //simply making a newline for easier console reading
  console.log('The word provided is: ', word);
  isWordAPalindrome('sherpa');
  console.log('sherpa is not a palindrome');
  isWordAPalindrome('stewie');
  console.log('stewie is not a palindrome');
  isWordAPalindrome('anna');
  console.log('anna is a palindrome');
  isWordAPalindrome('lil squiggle');
  console.log('lil squiggle is not a palindrome');
  isWordAPalindrome('racecar');
  console.log('racecar is a palindrome');
  isWordAPalindrome('tacocat');
  console.log('tacocat is a palindrome');
}
```

Comment: You would help yourself a great deal if you would indent your code properly. Furthermore, you have lots of things that don't make sense: `str[0];`? `str.length`? A block without any reason? A `return` leaving half of your code unexecuted?

Comment: You have a random code-block starting after an empty console log. Also, you have a bunch of variables scattered about with no assignment being done.

Answer (score 2):

Different approach:

```js
const word = "sherpa,stewie,anna,lil squiggle, A butt tuba, racecar, tacocat";

const a = word.split(',').map(s => s.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, ""));

const isP = s => s === s.split('').reverse().join('');

for (let w of a) {
 console.log(`${w}: ${isP(w)}`)
}
```

Comment: Works great, but I'd make sure to make it all one case: `const a = word.toLowerCase().split(',').map(s => s.trim());`. You could get "Racecar" (a palindrome), but in reverse it'd be "racecaR" which doesn't equal the original string.

Comment: Furthermore, instead of `s.trim()`, you might want to consider `s.replace(/\s+/g, '')`, which will remove all of the whitespace.  It's useful if you need 'Race car' to work.

Answer (score 1):

You have a return statement which stops the code execution and returns from the function. 
Here what you want to achieve

```
function checkPalindrome(word) {
  for (var i = 0, j = word.length -1; i++, j--; i < word.length, j >= 0, i < j) {
    if (word.charAt(i) !== word.charAt(j)) {
      return false;
    } 
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(checkPalindrome('sherpa'));
console.log(checkPalindrome('anna'));
```

Comment: Looks like you keep checking beyond the word's midpoint.  Something like this would stop once you've reached the midpoint: `var first = 0;
var last = word.length - 1;
/*optional: make sure the case is consistent and strip out any whitespace*/
word = word.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
while(first<last){
  if(word.charAt(first) !== word.charAt(last)){
    return false;
  }
}
return true;`

Comment: This check stops in the midpoint, and it's already in the code `&& i <= j`

Comment: I saw that, but how does that stop the for loop?

Comment: it stops the checks in my code, but if you want to stop the for loop you just have to move that condition in the for, code updated

Comment: Understandibly SUPER picky, but instead `i<=j` could you go with `i < j`.  If 'i' and 'j' are equal, then you'd be comparing a char to itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have code inside the isWordAPalindrom method that is after the return:

```
return isWordAPalindrome(str.slice(1,str.length-1));
//unreachable
isWordAPalindrome('word');
console.log('sherpa');
console.log('stewie');
...
```

that code is unreachable

Answer (score 0):

When you do **return** you are doing your thread "go out" of the function.

**Code after return can't be ever executed**, it is what the error is saying to you.

If you are trying to do something before the return statement, just put it before.

```
 isWordAPalindrome('word');
        console.log('sherpa');
        console.log('stewie');
        console.log('anna');
        console.log('lil squiggle');
        console.log('racecar');
        console.log('tacocat');
        return isWordAPalindrome(str.slice(1, str.length - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your recursive routine is fine. You just need to know where to start and end your tabs and braces.

Also, you were assigning the value `0` to your `str.length` instead of evaluating if it was equal (`===` *or at the very least* `==`).

Also, you can evaluate if the word is a palindrome before your print out the log message.

```js
var words = "sherpa, stewie, anna, lil squiggle, racecar, tacocat".split(/,\s*/);

words.forEach(word => {
  var isPalindrome = isWordAPalindrome(word);
  console.log(`${word} is ${!isPalindrome ? 'not ' : ''}a palindrome`);
});

function isWordAPalindrome(str) {
  if (str.length === 0) {
    return true;
  }
  if (str[0] != str[str.length - 1]) {
    return false;
  }
  return isWordAPalindrome(str.slice(1, str.length - 1));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

#### Output

```
sherpa is not a palindrome
stewie is not a palindrome
anna is a palindrome
lil squiggle is not a palindrome
racecar is a palindrome
tacocat is a palindrome
```